# 'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: npm, npm-install

edit: since this question was posted, typings have been deprecated in favor of @types.

---

#### Summary

I'm trying to install typescript typings for my web app, but I can't get command prompt to recognize the `typings` command.

#### The Problem

`typings install` throws the following error:

```
'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

#### Details

When I run `npm i typings -g`, the console tells me the module has been installed. But when I look in my global npm directory, there is no typings file.

```
C:\gitdev\MyWebApp\src\main\webapp\myUI>npm i typings -g
C:\home\123456\AppData\Roaming\npm\typings -> C:\home\123456\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typings\dist\bin.js
C:\home\123456\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- typings@2.1.1
```

#### More Details

my username has been replaced with `123456` for security purposes. everything else is copied verbatim.

I don't have admin privileges (i'm on a work machine)

`where typings` also throws an error (INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

npm -g worked fine for grunt-cli

npm is in my PATH as `C:\Users\123456\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 8):

Try to install typings using npm command : npm install typings --global

after that execute the typings command.
example: typings install dt~hammerjs --save --global

Comment: npm WARN deprecated typings@2.1.1: Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information

Answer (score 0):

Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings

**Solution**:

Install @types/npm
Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/npm